# Struggling to take the next step in how to store my data

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, nosql

I'm struggling with how to store some telemetry streams. I've played with a number of things, and I find myself feeling like I'm at a writer's block.

### Problem Description

Via a UDP connection, I receive telemetry from different sources. Each source is decomposed into a set of devices. And for each device there's at most 5 different value types I want to store. They come in no faster than once per minute, and may be sparse. The values are transmitted with a hybrid edge/level triggered scheme (send data for a value when it is either different enough or enough time has passed). So it's a 2 or 3 level hierarchy, with a dictionary of time series.

The thing I want to do most with the data is a) access the latest values and b) enumerate the timespans (begin/end/value). I don't really care about a lot of "correlations" between data. It's not the case that I want to compute averages, or correlate between them. Generally, I look at the latest value for given type, across all or some hierarchy derived subset. Or I focus one one value stream and am enumerating the spans.

I'm not a database expert at all. In fact I know very little. And my three colleagues aren't either. I do python (and want whatever I do to be python3). So I'd like whatever we do to be as approachable as possible. I'm currently trying to do development using Mint Linux. I don't care much about ACID and all that.

### What I've Done So Far

1. Our first version of this used the Gemstone Smalltalk database. Building a specialized Timeseries object worked like a charm. I've done a lot of Smalltalk, but my colleagues haven't, and the Gemstone system is NOT just a "jump in and be happy right away". And we want to move away from Smalltalk (though I wish the marketplace made it otherwise). So that's out.
2. Played with RRD (Round Robin Database). A novel approach, but we don't need the compression that bad, and being edge triggered, it doesn't work well for our data capture model.
3. A friend talked me into using sqlite3. I may try this again. My first attempt didn't work out so well. I may have been trying to be too clever. I was trying to do things the "normalized" way. I found that I got something working at first OK. But getting the "latest" value for given field for a subset of devices, was getting to be some hairy (for me) SQL. And the speed for doing so was kind of disappointing. So it turned out I'd need to learn about indexing too. I found I was getting into a hole I didn't want to. And headed right back where we were with the Smalltalk DB, lot of specialized knowledge, me the only person that could work with it.
4. I thought I'd go the "roll your own" route. My data is not HUGE. Disk is cheap. And I know real well how to read/write files. And aren't filesystems hierarchical databases anyway? I'm sure that "people in the know" are rolling their eyes at this primitive approach, but this method was the most approachable. With a little bit of python code, I used directories for my structuring, and then a 2 file scheme for each value (one for the latest value, and an append log for the rest of the values). This has worked OK. But I'd rather not be liable for the wrinkles I haven't quite worked out yet. There's as much code involved in how the data is serialized to/from (just using simple strings right now). One nice thing about this approach, is that while I can write python scripts to analyze the data, some things can be done just fine with classic command line tools. E.g (simple query to show all latest rssi values).

   `ls Telemetry/*/*/rssi | xargs cat`
5. I spent this morning looking at alternatives. Growsed the NOSQL sites. Read up on PyTables. Scanned ZODB tutorial. PyTables looks very suited for what I'm after. Hierarchy of named tables modeling timeseries. But I don't think PyTables works with python3 yet (at least, there is no debian/ubuntu package for python3 yet). Ditto for ZODB. And I'm afraid I don't know enough about what the many different NOSQL databases do to even take a stab at one.

### Plea for Ideas

I find myself more bewildered and confused than at the start of this. I was probably too naive that I'd find something that could be a little more "fire and forget" and be past it at this point. Any advice and direction you have, would be hugely appreciated. If someone can give me a recipe that I can meet my needs without huge amounts of overhead/education/ingress, I'd mark that as the answer for sure.

Comment: Can you provide a better sample of the input? Does a device send a number every few seconds and you want to store this? Just not sure why a row in sqlite3 with the column 'device','timestamp','value1','value2...' doesn't meet your need.

Comment: @Jonathan: Every minute I get a packet for a group of devices, with sparsely keyed values (iow, it doesn't necessarily include all of value1, value2, and value3 each time, but may include value1 one time, value2 and value3 next time, so on and so forth). My last attempt was a 'device, timestamp, value, valueType' scheme (with linked tables for valueTypes and unique devices). And then after much wrangling, a LatestValues VIEW.

Comment: What you describe still fits the model proposed.... one table, one column for each value, and leave those columns null/empty if there wasn't an update in the last packet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe fits the database model (ex, sqlite3).

Keep one table.

```
id, device_id, valuetype1, valuetype2, valuetype3, ... ,valuetypen, timestamp
```

*I assume all devices are of the same type (IE, have the same set of values that you care about). If they do not, consider simply setting the value=null when it doesn't apply to a specific device type.*

### Each time you get an update, duplicate the last row and update the newest value:

```
INSERT INTO DeviceValueTable (device_id, valuetype1, valuetype2,..., timestamp) 
    SELECT device_id, valuetype1, @new_value, ...., NOW()
        FROM DeviceValueTable
        WHERE device_id = @device_id
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1;
```

### To get the latest values for a specific device:

```
SELECT *
    FROM DeviceValueTable
    WHERE device_id = @device_id         
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

### To get the latest values for all devices:

```
select
    DeviceValueTable.*
from
    DeviceValueTable a
    inner join 
        (select id, max(timestamp) as newest 
         from DeviceValueTable group by device_id) as b on
        a.id = b.id
```

You might be worried about the cost (size of storing) the duplicate values. Rely on the database to handle compression.
Also, keep in mind simplicity over optimization. Make it work, then if it's too slow, find and fix the slowness.

*Note, these queries were not tested on sqlite3 and may contain typos.*

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm going to take a stab at this.

We use Elastic Search for a lot of our unstructured data: http://www.elasticsearch.org/. I'm no expert on this subject, but in my day-to-day, I rely on the indices a lot. Basically, you post JSON objects to the index, which lives on some server. You can query the index via the URL, or by posting a JSON object to the appropriate place. I use [pyelasticsearch](http://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to connect to the indices---that package is well-documented, and the main class that you use is thread-safe.

The query language is pretty robust itself, but you could just as easily add a field to the records in the index that is "latest time" before you post the records.

Anyway, I don't feel that this deserves a check mark (even if you go that route), but it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want an on-disk, implicitly sorted datastructure like a btree or similar.

Maybe check out:

```
http://liw.fi/larch/
http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxBeeBase/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't technical, its poor problem specification.

If you are doing anything with sensor data then the old laboratory maxim applies "If you don't write it down, it didn't happen". In the lab, that means a notebook and pen, on a computer it means ACID.

You also seem to be prematurely optimizing the solution, which is well known to [be the root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29). You don't say what size the data are, but you do say they "come no faster than once per minute, and may be sparse". Assuming they are an even 1.0KB in size, that's 1.5MB/day or 5.3GB/year. My StupidPhone has more storage than you would need in a year, and my laptop has sneezes that are larger.

The biggest problem is that you claim to "know very little" about databases and that is the crux of the matter. Your data is standard old 1950s data-processing boring. You're jumping into buzzword storage technologies when SQLite would do everything you need if only you knew how to ask it. Given that you've got Smalltalk DB down, I'd be quite surprised if it took more than a day's study to learn all the conventional RDBM principles you need and then some.

After that, you'd be able to write a question that can be answered in more than generalities.

Comment: I'm not trying to overly optimize the solution I don't think. At least, not from a storage scheme. I think the "gazillion little files" proves that. The disk usage of that scheme is ridiculous. What I am trying to "optimize" is the time I have to spend getting into this, as well as the time it would take colleagues to approach the data or do maintenance. The data stream HAS been optimized. But not before we did the "make it work, make it right, make it fast" approach, which happened when cell modem data bills started rolling in with pretty high figures (http is not a good idea for this stuff)

Comment: Which is precisely why I am recommending that you use well known, well documented, wildly accessible RDMB technology. "If you can trivially load your data into Excel, it can probably be handled by most people who might want to use it" — _me_ (2013)

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure how to take your response. It sounds like your (now) saying "go back to your sqlite3 approach, don't give up yet, you'll get there." Which I appreciate. Thanks!